# How to add product2 in standard price book in Salesforce CRM?

Tags: .net, c, salesforce, crm, salesforce-service-cloud

I have created a product2 but  i am being unable to add standard price to that product in asp.net application.here is my code

```
Product2 p = new Product2();
    p.Name = "randi";
    p.IsActive = true;
    saveresults = SfdcBinding.create(new sObject[] { p });
    p.Id = saveresults[0].id;

     QueryResult qr = SfdcBinding.query("select ID, Name, IsStandard from PriceBook2 WHERE IsStandard=true");
    sObject[] records = qr.records;
    string ID = records[0].Id;



    PricebookEntry pbe = new PricebookEntry();
    pbe.Pricebook2Id = ID;
    pbe.Product2Id=p.Id;
    pbe.IsActive=true;
    pbe.UnitPrice=100.0;
    pbe.UseStandardPrice= false;`enter code here`
   saveresults =  SfdcBinding.create(new sObject[] { pbe });
```

but it is not working? can anybody help me please?

Comment: whats the error SFDC is throwing ?

Comment: ERROR IS SIMPLE SFORCE.REFRENCE ERROR(UNIT PRICE IS MISSING)

Comment: just check the flag  pbe.UseStandardPrice=true and try